# Unable to install any packages in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I am unable to install any package in python even after downloading  zip file by referring to path .
If you are user not admin of system then how we can install it . 
`Showing error SSL: certification verification failed`.
Everytime

I tried to install `tkinter`.

```
Pip install setup.py
```

by going into the folder .
Please help.

Comment: If you are on a mac, you can `brew install python` in order to set up python properly. This will give you `python` along with a working `pip`

Comment: There's so many things wrong this this post.... 1. if you have a setup.py it's `python setup.py install`, 2. SSL error can occur when pip is installing from the internet, you need to add a trusted host, search your error message in SO there's tons a dupe questions, 3. tkinter is built-in to python, you don't have to install it, (maybe tk/tkl but not the package tkinter) 4. If you're already using anaconda, use conda to install packages.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install --user package_name`

This one should probably work 99% of the times.

BTW Tkinter comes preinstalled if you are using python 3.1 and above. Try the below commands to verify

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter._test()
```